# spring-boot-starter-quartz specify different db connector?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring boot application that is working correctly
with quartz job that is working correctly
all quartz related tables are created on FOO schema that is specified in the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

how do I specify a different DB schema only for the quartz objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use another datasource for quartz-schedulers you have to create a bean data-source annotated with **@QuartzDataSource**

```
@Bean
@QuartzDataSource
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
}
```

---

To have Quartz use a DataSource other than the application’s main DataSource, declare a DataSource bean, annotating its @Bean method with @QuartzDataSource. Doing so ensures that the Quartz-specific DataSource is used by both the SchedulerFactoryBean and for schema initialization.

---

Related docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html